# Collate data with respect to ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a table - `table_test`, with data like: 
[image]

I'm to trying to write an SQL query so I can get result in below format like:
[image]

That's data is collated wrt to ANSWER_IDs. So I can fetch resultsets with `ANSWER_ID` as a key.

I tried using `GROUPBY` but it will not work.

Even if it involves wiring procedures or functions, please suggest.

Apologies if this question sounds vague.

Comment: Rahul, is it ok to repeat the answer_id on every line? Also, Is it ok to not draw the horizontal lines between the groups?

Comment: Should **Bulb** have `ANSWER_ID` of `1` or `2`? The sample data and output look inaccurate.

Comment: That looks like a **reporting** task (formatting the output **for human consumption only**) - you would never do that in an intermediate step used in further processing. As such, it is best done in your reporting tool (software, interface, whatever) you use to prepare final reports, not in a SQL statement or PL/SQL code. The best answer so far, from those offered, is Littlefoot's answer, showing you how to do this in SQL*Plus, if that's what you use as your **report writing tool**. The `BREAK` command he shows is not a SQL or PL/SQL command, it is a SQL\*Plus output formatting command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used SQL*Plus (no wonder if you don't; I'm afraid that not many people do nowadays), a simple `break` would do the job:

```
SQL> break on deptno
SQL>
SQL> select deptno, ename, sal from emp order by deptno, ename;

    DEPTNO ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
        10 CLARK            2450
           KING             5000
           MILLER           1300
        20 ADAMS            1100
           FORD             3000
           JONES            2975
           SCOTT            3000
           SMITH             800
        30 ALLEN            1600
           BLAKE            2850
           JAMES             950
           MARTIN           1250
           TURNER           1500
           WARD             1250

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working as required. But can we do it in stored procedure?

Comment: You're welcome. `break` won't work in PL/SQL. For that approach, see what other people have answered. Basically, you'd use one of analytic functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function here to achieve this result -

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ANSWER_ID = LAG(ANSWER_ID) OVER(ORDER BY ANSWER_ID)
            THEN NULL ELSE ANSWER_ID END ANSWER_ID
      ,ANSWER_KEY
      ,VALUE
FROM table_test;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a rank to each record within groups having the same `answer_id`, and only print `answer_id` for records numbered as 1:

```
SELECT
    DECODE(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY answer_id ORDER BY value, answer_key), 1, answer_id) answer_id,
    answer_key,
    value
FROM mytable x
ORDER BY x.answer_id, x.value, x.answer_key
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5492203aa40b58445f9f161f13a499ff)** with your sample data returns:

```
ANSWER_ID | ANSWER_KEY | VALUE
--------: | :--------- | ----:
        1 | Apples     |    10
     null | Oranges    |    14
     null | Oranges    |    22
        2 | Bulb       |    11
     null | LED        |    11
     null | Neon       |    11
        3 | Porsche    |   114
     null | BMW        |   120
```

However, please bear in mind that this is a mostly cosmetic operation that does not actually *collapses* or *folds* data in any way; as with any SQL query, data is returned as a flat table, not as a kind of imbricated data structure.